# scheduled message feature removed?

Tags: sms, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I've upgraded my Galaxy Note II to Android 4.3 and if I open the menu when writing an SMS there is no scheduled message option anymore. Where is it gone?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung probably felt the "non-need" of this feature, hence removing it.

You could either use apps from the play store such as "Schemes" which allows you to schedule messaging, or contact Samsung support via email requesting the re-addition of the feature (I'd go with the former because, one mail mostly doesn't make a difference against a huge OEM).